# how do i let text fit to UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel

### problem:

Button size is enough, however when I change title, the title text cannot fit the button width. Any SDK function can solve this problem, or I need to manually code to solve it?

Please refer to following pictures.

design in the nib file. 
[image]

initial show in simulator
[image]

when I change the title text
[image]

### tried some ways before

1. _button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
   the way will change my font size. I cannot accept the way.
2. [_button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 0.0,0.0)];  
   the way change label's position only, not label size.
3. [_button.titleLabel sizeToFit];
   result is same with picture(3).
4. [_button sizeToFit]; 
   title moved to upper left corner, and the title still the same result.

Just confused, my button size is big enough, why title size is so small?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use this.

Objective-c

```
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
```

Swift 2.0

```
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

NOTE: Swift code courtesy: @Rachel Harvey

Swift 5.0

```
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

Comment: `button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;` That line alone should do the trick

Comment: I recently edited this for Swift 2 and to make the words wrap:`button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
button.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping`

Comment: In `Swift` code, `.numberOfLines` should be `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: `Note` If using attributed text then try `NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail`.

Comment: I had to add: `self.shareButton.titleLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentNone;` to prevent text from dropping down (iOS 10)

Answer (score 14):

For people who come across with this question:

Try using the setter:

```
 [self.myButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [self.myButton sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure also that the label doesn't adjust later spacing, as that seems to take precedence over adjusting font size. Also make sure the minimumScaleFactor < 1.

```
button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
button.titleLabel.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth = NO;
button.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Swift version:

```
    let button = UIButton()
    button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
    button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByClipping
```

Answer (score 0):

In IB, just select the button, go to the editor menu, and choose "Size To Fit Content"

Comment: hi, I tried, but not solve my problem. I have update (3)(4). thanks

Comment: btw, where is the setting on IB "size to fit", I cannot find it in IB. I just find 'scale to fit' in XCode4.5

Comment: It should be "Size To Fit Content", I've updated my answer. It's where I said it was -- under the Editor menu. Doing that in IB is different from using sizeToFit in code.

Comment: I got it. editor > "Size To Fit Content", and I remove code mentioned (3) and (4), and tried again. the result is still same. see picture3. thanks

Comment: I don't know what to say -- it works for me. It may have something to do with the layout constraints.

Comment: yep, sometimes it's strange on IB. I uncheck autolayout setting when I deal with IB.

Comment: But, I think that "Size To Fit Content" might only work when you use auto layout.